# Unable to reference new environments with RefTeX

Tags: cross-referencing, auctex, reftex

I was trying to add new environments to AUCTeX doing what the RefTeX's manual says, so I added the following to my .emacs:

```lisp
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-reftex)

(setq reftex-label-alist
   '(("axiom"   ?a "ax:"  "~\\ref{%s}" nil ("axiom"   "ax.") -2)
     ("theorem" ?h "thr:" "~\\ref{%s}" t   ("theorem" "th.") -3)))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
   (lambda ()
     (LaTeX-add-environments
       '("axiom" LaTeX-env-label)
       '("theorem" LaTeX-env-label))))
```

The problem is that i have to reference these labels manually. 
I've tried to do what the RefTeX manual says:

> For example if you write: ‘As we have shown in Theorem’and then press C-c ), RefTeX will know that you are looking for a theorem label and restrict the menu to only these labels without even asking.

But with the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{axiom}{Axiom}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{axiom}
  \label{ax:1}
  An axiom
\end{axiom}
\begin{theorem}
  \label{thr:1}
  A theorem
\end{theorem}

As we have shown in Theorem
\end{document}
```

it does not work, because it shows me the Axiom and the Theorem and doesn't even let me choose one (so I have to press <kbd>s</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> and then choose one).

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: The version of reftex that comes with emacs is based on reftex 4.31. The current version of reftex is 4.34. It contains, among others, the following two changes:

> 2008-05-03  Ralf Angeli
>
> - lisp/reftex-parse.el (reftex-parse-from-file): Move backward one
>         char if a `\' was matched after a section macro.
>
> 2008-04-13  Ralf Angeli
>
> - lisp/reftex-parse.el (reftex-parse-from-file): Use beginning of
>         match instead of end as bound.

You can also see the relevant bits here:

https://github.com/DamienCassou/RefTeX/commit/5f341de11651f7ec7eaed11f8faf0b2019a3b089

https://github.com/DamienCassou/RefTeX/commit/c1468af43fc660511551dc5a5ba5585db68e5cfc

Those two commits fix your problem. If you'd like to know more about what the problem is, please read on :)

You've associated the type "h" with theorems (through the ?h in `reftex-label-alist`). If you press `C-c )` after the word *Theorem*, `reftex-reference` will be called and it will guess that you want a reference of type "h". You can also explicitly call `(reftex-reference "h")` from anywhere. `reftex-reference` is just a wrapper around `reftex-offer-label-menu`. You can thus also just call `(reftex-offer-label-menu "h")` to see a list of references (except that, again, it will be empty). That function is again a wrapper around `reftex-insert-docstruct` that is called in a temporary read-only buffer with special navigation handling.

In `reftex-insert-docstruct`, information on labels is retrieved from `(symbol-value reftex-docstruct-symbol)`, which is filled through `reftex-access-scan-info`. The corresponding variable contains plenty of data. Here's what matters:

If you execute the following snippet of code in your minibuffer (using `M-:`):

```
(let (ls)
  (reftex-access-scan-info)
  (dolist (i (symbol-value reftex-docstruct-symbol) ls)
    (when (stringp (car i))
      (push (concat "Label: " (nth 0 i) ", Type: " (nth 1 i)) ls))))
```

you should get the following output:

```
("Label: thr:1, Type: s" "Label: ax:1, Type: s")
```

That tells you that the labels thr:1 and ax:1 have type "s" rather than "h" and "a", respectively. You can also double-check that by replacing <kbd>s</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> with <kbd>s</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> in your workflow.

In the above, `reftex-access-scan-info` populates `reftex-docstruct-symbol`. It does that by tying `reftex-docstruct-symbol` to a variable using `reftex-tie-multifile-symbols` and the calling `reftex-do-parse`, which calls `reftex-parse-from-file`.

`reftex-parse-from-file` parses the TeX buffer by repeatedly searching using the regular expression `reftex-everything-regexp`; during scanning, that will look something like this:

```
"\\\\label{\\([^}]*\\)}\\|\\(^\\)[  ]*\\\\\\(begin{theorem}\\|begin{axiom}\\|part\\|chapter\\|section\\|subsection\\|subsubsection\\|frametitle\\|paragraph\\|subparagraph\\|addchap\\|addsec\\)\\*?\\(\\[[^]]*\\]\\)?[[{   \n]\\|\\(^\\)[  ]*\\\\\\(include\\|input\\)[{   ]+\\([^}    \n]+\\)\\|\\(^\\)[  ]*\\(\\\\appendix\\)\\|\\(\\\\glossary\\|\\\\index\\)[[{]"
```

Once it finds a match, it checks what pair of parentheses contains captured something. For the theorem and axiom environments and their labels, we get two matches -- that makes these environments different from e.g. *equation*, since there we only get a match for the label.

The first match, for the environment, comes from `reftex-section-labels-all`; 
it's what causes the problem (as already pointed out by @T.Verron). Anything matched by that will be treated as a section (and thus get a label of type "s").

That is why replacing

```
(setq reftex-label-alist
   '(("axiom"   ?a "ax:"  "~\\ref{%s}" nil ("axiom"   "ax.") -2)
     ("theorem" ?h "thr:" "~\\ref{%s}" t   ("theorem" "th.") -3)))
```

with

```
(setq reftex-label-alist
   '(("axiom"   ?a "ax:"  "~\\ref{%s}" nil ("axiom"   "ax."))
     ("theorem" ?h "thr:" "~\\ref{%s}" t   ("theorem" "th."))))
```

serves as a workaround: it removes the first match.

Answer (score 1):

As a quick fix, you can set the toc variable to `nil`.

From the RefTeX manual :

> A negative value will make unnumbered entries. Useful only for theorem-
>   like environments which structure the document. Will be ignored for
>   macros.

I fail to see how theorem-like environments are supposed to structure the document, but I understand that a label with negative depth in toc isn't made for crossreferencing.

A positive value works under some circumstances for me, and doesn't under others.

```
(setq reftex-label-alist
   '(("axiom"   ?a "ax:"  "~\\ref{%s}" nil ("axiom"   "ax."))
     ("theorem" ?h "thr:" "~\\ref{%s}" t   ("theorem" "th."))))
```